# How to force OpenSSL to use same certificate-chain validation algorithm used by Chrome Browser and SSL LABS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, chrome, glib

**Question:**  How can I force OpenSSL to use the same certificate validation algorithm used by the Chrome Browser and SSL Labs?

**Details:**

The certificate chain sent by "adswizz.com" includes a recently expired certificate from COMODO (expired May 30, 2020).

This OpenSSL command uses a simple algorithm that walks the cert-chain provided by the server, finds the expired certificate, and then reports "Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)".

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect adswizz.com:443 -servername adswizz.com < /dev/null
```

In contrast, visiting this SSL Labs URL shows the results from a more sophisticated algorithm that explores several different paths attempting to validate the server certificate.

```
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=adswizz.com
```

This finds 3 possible paths (see image below).  Path #2 is the same path used by OpenSSL, so it fails due to the expired certificate, ... but Paths #1 and #3 both succeed.  (Path #3 even downloads an additional certicate!)

We want to use `openssl` from the Linux command line, and use the `glib-openssl` library to support TLS communication with the server.  What command-line options or library config settings can we use to force OpenSSL to validate a certificate and get the same result as the Chrome Browser.

We cannot force the 3rd party running the `adswizz.com` to update its certificate chain because they will "check" using Chrome and tell is, "Looks valid", ... but OpenSSL will still fail.

We need a fix or a workaround.  Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
# openssl s_client -showcerts -connect adswizz.com:443 -servername adswizz.com < /dev/null

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=May 30 10:48:38 2020 GMT
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.adswizz.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGEzCCA/ugAwIBAgIQfVtRJrR2uhHbdBYLvFMNpzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB
iDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkxFDASBgNVBAcTC0pl
cnNleSBDaXR5MR4wHAYDVQQKExVUaGUgVVNFUlRSVVNUIE5ldHdvcmsxLjAsBgNV
BAMTJVVTRVJUcnVzdCBSU0EgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMTgx
MTAyMDAwMDAwWhcNMzAxMjMxMjM1OTU5WjCBjzELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNV
BAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEYMBYGA1UE
ChMPU2VjdGlnbyBMaW1pdGVkMTcwNQYDVQQDEy5TZWN0aWdvIFJTQSBEb21haW4g
VmFsaWRhdGlvbiBTZWN1cmUgU2VydmVyIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC
AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1nMz1tc8INAA0hdFuNY+B6I/x0HuMjDJsGz99J/LEpgPLT+N
TQEMgg8Xf2Iu6bhIefsWg06t1zIlk7cHv7lQP6lMw0Aq6Tn/2YHKHxYyQdqAJrkj
eocgHuP/IJo8lURvh3UGkEC0MpMWCRAIIz7S3YcPb11RFGoKacVPAXJpz9OTTG0E
oKMbgn6xmrntxZ7FN3ifmgg0+1YuWMQJDgZkW7w33PGfKGioVrCSo1yfu4iYCBsk
Haswha6vsC6eep3BwEIc4gLw6uBK0u+QDrTBQBbwb4VCSmT3pDCg/r8uoydajotY
uK3DGReEY+1vVv2Dy2A0xHS+5p3b4eTlygxfFQIDAQABo4IBbjCCAWowHwYDVR0j
BBgwFoAUU3m/WqorSs9UgOHYm8Cd8rIDZsswHQYDVR0OBBYEFI2MXsRUrYrhd+mb
+ZsF4bgBjWHhMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBhjASBgNVHRMBAf8ECDAGAQH/AgEAMB0G
A1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAbBgNVHSAEFDASMAYGBFUdIAAw
CAYGZ4EMAQIBMFAGA1UdHwRJMEcwRaBDoEGGP2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudXNlcnRydXN0
LmNvbS9VU0VSVHJ1c3RSU0FDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uQXV0aG9yaXR5LmNybDB2Bggr
BgEFBQcBAQRqMGgwPwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGM2h0dHA6Ly9jcnQudXNlcnRydXN0LmNv
bS9VU0VSVHJ1c3RSU0FBZGRUcnVzdENBLmNydDAlBggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDov
L29jc3AudXNlcnRydXN0LmNvbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFAAOCAgEAMr9hvQ5Iw0/H
ukdN+Jx4GQHcEx2Ab/zDcLRSmjEzmldS+zGea6TvVKqJjUAXaPgREHzSyrHxVYbH
7rM2kYb2OVG/Rr8PoLq0935JxCo2F57kaDl6r5ROVm+yezu/Coa9zcV3HAO4OLGi
H19+24rcRki2aArPsrW04jTkZ6k4Zgle0rj8nSg6F0AnwnJOKf0hPHzPE/uWLMUx
RP0T7dWbqWlod3zu4f+k+TY4CFM5ooQ0nBnzvg6s1SQ36yOoeNDT5++SR2RiOSLv
xvcRviKFxmZEJCaOEDKNyJOuB56DPi/Z+fVGjmO+wea03KbNIaiGCpXZLoUmGv38
sbZXQm2V0TP2ORQGgkE49Y9Y3IBbpNV9lXj9p5v//cWoaasm56ekBYdbqbe4oyAL
l6lFhd2zi+WJN44pDfwGF/Y4QA5C5BIG+3vzxhFoYt/jmPQT2BVPi7Fp2RBgvGQq
6jG35LWjOhSbJuMLe/0CjraZwTiXWTb2qHSihrZe68Zk6s+go/lunrotEbaGmAhY
LcmsJWTyXnW0OMGuf1pGg+pRyrbxmRE1a6Vqe8YAsOf4vmSyrcjC8azjUeqkk+B5
yOGBQMkKW+ESPMFgKuOXwIlCypTPRpgSabuY0MLTDXJLR27lk8QyKGOHQ+SwMj4K
00u/I5sUKUErmgQfky3xxzlIPK1aEn8=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.adswizz.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5334 bytes and written 454 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: B56072247A34ED804A1B84933F673D5029E02352C1EC96109F38991BCE1DA450
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 79A358537CE41E0CA4D3463848A9837397BB06B068547F702336723D42BB7DB0A788390E76F4264534D2B47EE2B1B48C
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 60 bb 34 9c c4 9e 1e d5-25 30 51 e8 c0 66 ad f9   `.4.....%0Q..f..
    0010 - 96 ff 5a 60 3b 9b 50 07-55 08 2b 11 5e 72 9e fb   ..Z`;.P.U.+.^r..
    0020 - b6 47 85 f1 42 27 28 ae-ce fc e0 63 c3 00 60 01   .G..B'(....c..`.
    0030 - 78 d0 6b c6 d9 40 8e 5d-96 14 a0 24 f2 4e 35 25   x.k..@.]...$.N5%
    0040 - 3e e4 94 21 c6 11 0b db-00 6b c7 16 87 c1 92 a2   >..!.....k......
    0050 - 9a c3 dc 51 95 5d 44 6f-e0 f0 20 2c 44 9e 07 e3   ...Q.]Do.. ,D...
    0060 - cb 0a 83 f2 8f 06 d8 9d-53 b8 85 a1 62 27 09 dd   ........S...b'..
    0070 - a2 74 35 31 07 71 5b 92-87 8e 84 34 c4 10 9f 01   .t51.q[....4....
    0080 - 0a 86 30 32 e4 b2 3e ed-3c c4 81 49 42 60 19 9b   ..02..>.<..IB`..
    0090 - ff 90 0b 0a a7 4b 58 ed-bd b9 6a 8a 09 3e 54 0e   .....KX...j..>T.
    00a0 - 39 ce 19 14 fb 5d b3 b6-11 a3 11 da 53 11 ff 06   9....]......S...
    00b0 - 0e 9c 1b 7f 14 ef 69 cb-35 5a 79 29 dd ed 9c 39   ......i.5Zy)...9
    00c0 - 19 e2 6a 9e d7 06 5e e7-3b 86 c1 0e cb 80 7e 6a   ..j...^.;.....~j

    Start Time: 1591065727
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
---
DONE
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> This OpenSSL command uses a simple algorithm that walks the cert-chain provided by the server, finds the expired certificate, and then reports "Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)".

While this is true for OpenSSL 1.0.2 it is no longer true for OpenSSL 1.1.1 - i.e. this version finds and uses the valid path.

> Path #3 even downloads an additional certicate!

While Chrome would do this neither Firefox nor OpenSSL nor many other libraries would download missing certificates by their own.

> We cannot force the 3rd party running the adswizz.com to update its certificate chain because they will "check" using Chrome and tell is, "Looks valid", ... but OpenSSL will still fail.

While it contains a grain of truth this argument is still wrong. Both servers and clients should have correct and up-to-date configuration. This means in this specific case your OpenSSL should be newer and also the server should be fixed. If the company is testing only with a single browser and ignoring problems with everything else it is risking loosing customers.